# Stuck at 800x600 display resolution Ubuntu 14

Tags: display, display-resolution

After dual booting Win 10/Ubuntu 14, Windows displays at 1366 x 768 with 10 display modes available.
Ubuntu has no options other than a "built-in" 800 x 600 low res output. The driver is the latest available for the AMD Radeon R6. This is for an HP Pavilion Notebook.

Research (mostly about nvidia cards) suggests use of `xrandr` and `cvt` commands in terminal which I've attempted without joy with a file attached containing outputs from various commands.

Notably,"size of gamma" and the name of the video device (ie, VGA) can't be found by `xrandr`.
What can be tried to access and use a resolution of 1368x768?
What is "gamma" and why can't xrandr find it?

---

Here is further information including commands/outputs.

```
Computer: an HP Pavilion Laptop 64bit dual-booted Windows 10/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Graphics card: AMD Radeon R6, chip: Ox9874
Driver:AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati(open source, tested)--recommended.
```

---

OUTPUT from `$>sudo lshw -C video`:

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:ff700000-ff73ffff memory:ff740000-ff75ffff
```

---

OUTPUT from `$>xrandr`:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
default connected primary 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        75.0*
```

---

OUTPUT using `cvt` with known max resolution from WIN 10 where 10 possible display modes exist....

```
~$> cvt 1366 768 60"

# 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784 768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

---

```
~$ lspci| grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 9874 (rev c5)
```

---

After attempting to add a newmode to xrandr and testing this output occurs;

```
~$ xrandr --newmode  "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

```
~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
default connected primary 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        75.0* 
  1368x768_60.00 (0x233)   85.2MHz
        h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock   47.8KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock   59.9Hz
```

---

When attempting to use >`xrandr` to `--addmode` these error messages occur:

```
xrandr --addmode default 1366x768_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find mode "1366x768_60.00"
```

---

additional attempt to get `xrandr` to accept a newmode and the resultant output:

```
~$ xrandr --newmode  "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

Comment: Is the resolution resolved with current updated 14.04?  We have a Radeon 9200 (RV280), and upon upgrade from 12.04 we used to have 800x600 (so I configured grub to use 3.2 kernel from 12.04 for some time); more recently 14.04 (with 3.13 default kernel) is using full monitor resolution.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem and here is what worked (well partially) for me:

1. Edited `/etc/default/grub` as root
2. Changed the line where GRUB_GFXMODE was set. It was earlier having the value 800x600. Changed it to 1366x768 (And don't forget to uncomment the line).
3. Ran `update-grub`
4. Rebooted.

Still no other resolutions are showing when I go to display properties but at least the default (rather the only resolution) is what I am comfortable with.

HTH

Venugopalan Govindan

Answer (score 1):

`xrandr` reports `Failed to get size of gamma for output default`.

So maybe you need to set the gamma size of your display. The format for this command using `xrandr` is:

```
xrandr --verbose --output monitor_name --gamma red:green:blue
```

You can find out your monitor name using:

```
xrandr | grep "connected"
```

You want to set the gamma size to it's default values, so it's `1:1:1`. For my display the command would look like:

```
xrandr --verbose --output DVI-I-1 --gamma 1:1:1
```

Try entering the `xrandr` commands again. You may need to restart your PC.

Comment: I tried the two commands. The one involving "grep" says "default connected" from which I presume a monitor name of "default." The xrandr process to force a gamma of " 1:1:1" using monitor name "default" then rebooting, still can't find the gamma using "xrandr." "xgamma" command outputs 1:1:1 but resolution is still stuck on 800x600. It seems I can input a gamma value, the computer records it but xrandr cannot find it. Now what can be tried? I do have a decent driver on the win10 side of the laptop. Can (or should) it be used?