# Ubuntu 16.04 Display Resolution 800x600

Tags: drivers, 16.04, display-resolution

Installed Ubuntu 16.04 in Parallels 11 on Macbook Pro Retina.

If during the installation I select "Try Ubuntu Without Installing" the display resolution is fine and xrandr shows resolutions of 640x480 up to 1920x1200 - it selects 1920x1200 - looks ok.

From this desktop I then select "Install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS" and proceed with the install. It installs fine.

After re-launching the display is now stuck at 800x600. xrandr says
Failed to get size of gamma for output default.
And the only resolution it shows is 800x600 - too low.

When I launched Additional Drivers it found 1 unknown one but said it was not working. Did not find an Nvidia driver.

The computer uses an Nvidia GEForce GT 650M chip.

Any suggestions? I know there are other similar posts but am stumped.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question and include the result of *lspci -nn | grep VGA*

Answer (score 4):

I used the work-around in

[Stuck at 800x600 display resolution Ubuntu 14](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728664/stuck-at-800x600-display-resolution-ubuntu-14?rq=1)

This increases the resolution to an acceptable level (2560x1440) by editing `/etc/default/grub` - changing to `GRUB_GFXMODE 2560x1440`.

However, I feel that the Nvidia driver is not installed properly so this is just a work-around...

Comment: In my case, the low screen resolution was because the newer NVIDIA driver was not working well (460). The solution was revert to the previous driver version (450), and the FHD resolution came back.

Answer (score 2):

You have to **update grub** too. After some updates on 16.04 (on Parallels) I've lost my display settings. That helps me:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
GRUB_GFXMODE=1440x900     # MacBookAir resolution
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable secure boot, you will get back all resolution of display as before installation of Nvidia driver. As it works

Answer (score 0):

You could try switching to proprietary drivers.
For example, I have GTX 1650 and for it to work properly I had to install proprietary drivers. Ubuntu allows doing this quite easy:

1. Search for **Additinol Drivers** applicaton in **Activities** search field[image]
2. Choose the driver you need and click on **Apply Changes** [image]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was switching my Nvidia drivers from 470 to 450 (based on [rogergo's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825259/ubuntu-16-04-display-resolution-800x600#comment2225189_825326)).